# How to display XML data extracted from db server to SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am writing a simple report in Reporting Services that displays data extracted from a single table. One of the table columns contains XML data, which I want to pass to the sub-report as a parameter.  This sub report should render the values in normal tabular format.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this on the SQL side. The more you can do in SQL the better. Take the XML and parse it into whatever format you would like, then it will be much easier to work with in SSRS

Comment: Thanks user782152 for looking into my issue. As I have many sub-reports which will acquire the parameter value in xml. There should be some external component which I will parse the xml value into normal datatable set and pass to the subreport(s) each as dataset. And if you ask why XML format?,  Basically I don't want to request the database all the time until the report is fully rendered.